# Shrink ADC signal from 5V to 1V?

Tags: adc, level-shifting

I have an ADC signal, how do I shrink it to 1V from a 5V sensor like Hall IC for example. Of course, a resistor divider is one method, but will it work reliably as the output is expected between 0 to 1V, so I am assuming, the margin of error would be high.
I have also seen some of the low voltage op amps like: LMV951 but the cost is pretty high, instead for that cost, I would choose a separate ADC chip.
Is there a way to reliably do the level conversion at the minimum cost, high accuracy is really not required. The micro controller can do 10 bit ADC, but I may be interested in only 8 bit accuracy.

Comment: What's wrong with the resistor divider?

Comment: What makes you think a resistor divider wouldn't do the job and how would an op-amp circuit be able to do the job without a similar sort of resistive attenuation?

Comment: Honestly, no idea, please excuse my ignorance. I am just wondering whether resistor divider can be reliable, so looking for alternatives like LTC4308, LMV951, etc. but seems too costly for my requirement, so just wondering whether there is a low voltage signal convertor (mosfet transistor  based)

Comment: Does the ADC have an external reference pin? Will it accept 5V as the reference?

Comment: No doesn't have any reference voltage for ADC.

Comment: "Will it work reliably?"  Nothing much more reliable than two 1% resistors.

Comment: Regarding the opamp, i see this link: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/104324/7203, which is the same thing, but the signal is 0 to 5V and output needed is 0 to 1V

Comment: @ tcrosley, I see people put caps on the resistor divider network, it is necessary in my case? resistor I can understand 1 and 4x, but if caps are needed, how the value is chosen.

Comment: What is the input resistance or maximum input current specification of the ADC? And input capacitance, if you know it.

The capacitors would be used to improve the bandwidth of the resistor divider. Normally a resistor divider forms a low pass filter due to ADC input capacitance. The capacitors in parallel with the resistors create an AC resistor divider, so to speak. The value would be chosen based on signal bandwidth characteristics and input capacitance value, etc.

Comment: The op-amp circuit you linked has at least four resistors that are important for it to work and all four can affect gain and offset. Why on earth would this be better than using 2 resistors to attenuate a signal.

Answer (score 1):

A resistor divider is perfectly fine for the task. There is no real reason to reduce the voltage to 1V. If your ADC reference is 3.3V, make a resistor divider to reduce the voltage from 5V to 3.3V and have a full scale measurement. Beware to include the resistor divider tolerances into calculation, so you might end up having a resistor divider set up for somewhere between 0V and 3.2V. You can also do 0V to 3V in order to calculate values more easily in terms of math.

Comment: The chip only measure from 0 to 1V, not 3.3V. That's what I was worried, as from 5V to 3.3V not much level shifting, but for 1V there are not much chips also for ADC level conversion and the signal value needs to be reduced to 1/5th.

Comment: That's still fine. Take 1% resistors for better accuracy. People measuring 450V DC with microcontrollers and it's fine.