# Simple UA741 inverting amplifier not Working

Tags: amplifier, non-inverting

I'm building a simple non-inverting amplifier using [UA741](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ua741.pdf),The gain should be of about 11,and the input is 500m v dc so the output should be in the range of 5.5 volts however i'm getting about 0.45 volts.I'v tried changing the bais voltage many times from 15 to 32 volts but the result is the same.
[image: The Circut]

PLease Help....

Comment: Seems like you forgot to connect battery's negative to ground.

Comment: @RohatKılıç connecting the neg of the battery to ground won't help - it's not a rail to rail device (it's a dinosaur actually).

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the inputs of the 741 (any op-amp, in fact) are within the input common mode range. On the 741, that range is within 3V of each supply rail, according to the datasheet. The output also cannot swing all the way to either supply rail.

If you use supplies of +/-15V (the common must be grounded) then the circuit should work, however you show only a single power supply of +30V with no ground reference. If it is, in fact, floating as you show the circuit will not work, and it will not work if either side of the 30V supply is grounded. You also cannot use a voltage divider because current flows to the ground through R1. You could use another op-amp connected as a unity-gain buffer and a pair of equal value resistors (eg. 10K each) as a 'rail splitter'.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb5SfH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or swap the ancient LM741 out for half an LM358 and ground the (-) of the 30V supply and things will be okay (for positive inputs only).

Comment: Thanks a lot that really worked....But the gain should be 11 and in the output i'm getting 3.4 volts.How is that...??

Comment: What really worked? Something is obviously very wrong.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what i should do now..?

Comment: Maybe document the actual circuit you built and what voltages you measure at each node

Answer (score 1):

Earth (aka ground, aka 0 volts) is normally associated with the mid-point of the power rails so, either split the 30V in two halves and call the middle node "earth" or make a mid rail by using two resistors forming a potential divider (R1 can also become 2 resistors; a 2 kohm resistor to battery negative and a 2 kohm resistor to battery positive).

Alternatively (for R1) connect it to either rail via a high value capacitor (assuming that the application is for AC signal amplification such as audio): -

[image]

In the circuit above the input can be referenced to the most negative end of the battery - R3 and R4 form a rail splitter centreing the non-inverting input. C2's impedance needs to be significantly smaller than R1's resistance at all signal frequencies.

Here's the "inverting" version of the same circuit: -

[image]

Pictures taken from [**here**](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/circuits/opamp_inverting/op_amp_inverting.php) and that site will probably be worth studying to learn other op-amp basics.

See also [Choosing resistor values for Op-amp and inverting/non-inverting configuration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104314/choosing-resistor-values-for-op-amp-and-inverting-non-inverting-configuration) for a similar configuration

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question @Spehro

Comment: @Spehro 2x 2k resistors splitting the rails is the same as 1x 1k resistor to the midpoint voltage.  If DC isn't an issue a capacitor to either rail and keeping the original 1k resistor will also work.    The OP still needs to generate a midpoint for the the input.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you perfectly...so can you attach a schematic design of what i should do.

Comment: @MohamedRushdy done.

Comment: This won't work for low frequency inputs, obviously.

Comment: @ScottSeidman  do you think I didn't make it obvious enough in my answer?

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help,but can't you give me a DC design as i'm dealing with a pure DC signal.

Comment: @MohamedRushdy then you need to do what I said in the 1st paragraph.